# .NET 7 https endpoint configuration error

Tags: asp.net, ssl, .net-7.0

so i've been trying to get this http endpoint configured for my asp .net project (on macOS) for hours and am getting nowhere. I'm getting the following error upon running `dotnet run`:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to
> configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the
> default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date. To
> generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To
> trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs
> https --trust'.

obviously i've tried this solution, i've also tried deleting all the localhost certificates manually from keychain and running the `--verbose` and `--check` commands and everything seems to look good, but still the same error upon running the program.

here's my launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:25736",
      "sslPort": 44375
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i'm using the minimal hosting model, and there doesn't seem to be anything else in the project files about http or ssl connections besides the string to connect to my front end. the API isn't running on its own though, let alone when hooked up to the FE.

Any other tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any reference to HTTPS and you should be able to start the application as an HTTP-only application.

Comment: tried this just now, no dice :(

Comment: Let's do it again, remove all certs and try the following:

dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --verbose

Post your results.

Comment: CN=localhost - Valid from 2022-12-10 17:48:50Z to 2023-12-10 17:48:50Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true
and it says it's a valid certificate

Comment: Hmm, lets try in a different way. Generate the certificate to a specific path like so:
dotnet dev-certs https --certificate-output-path path/to/certificate.pfx

Then under launchSettings.json, add your cert:
"iisSettings": {
  ...
  "certificates": {
    "development": {
      "path": "path/to/certificate.pfx",
      "password": "password"
    }
  }
}

Restart app.

Comment: so i ran `dotnet dev-certs https --export-path path/to/cert.pfx` and it generated the cert but the password bit i don't quite understand

Comment: The PFX is protected by a password, so you should be able to write a password. Try with the -p flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250330/discussion-between-m-k-and-feras-wilson).